# Cryptic checksum error

Tags: texlive, debian, texlive-2016, tlmgr

Executing the `tlmgr update --all` command returns rather cryptic error message:

```
/usr/local/bin/tlmgr: checksum error when downloading /tmp/NAmys4kViD/eBXC4uTwZY
from ftp://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb:
digest disagree
```

I have successfully installed the Texlive 2016 distribution few days ago and it's fully operational (I can compile simple LaTeX documents). How can I repair it?

Here is the output of `tex --version`:

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

Comment: Try again, seems like some transient error during downloading.